# Conditional format based on Time Range in Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, conditional

is there a way to conditional format based on the time range or time value? i have a SPO list where employees have a daily task that is due at 5pm everyday. i wanted to conditional format the column where if the time value is <=5:00pm the column will turn green and if <5:00pm will turn red.

can this be achieved in SPO? using JSON syntax or any other way?

thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the data type of your "time" column? is it date & time column or something else?

Comment: the data type i have is number but the column type is calculated value because i am extracting the time value from the modified column.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with several caveats:

- `@now` will return the current time (at render) in the local timezone for the user
- `toLocaleTimeString` may return different formats depending on the user's browser locale
- The expression below is assuming time in a 12 hour clock with the hour first separated with a colon from the next value. If the localetimestring is different the expression will need to be adjusted
- If the list is open at 4:59pm it will be green and won't turn red at 5pm until the list item is either updated or the view is refreshed
- There is no lower bounds. If the time is AM it will be green, otherwise it checks the hour is earlier than 5
- If you want to include exactly 5:00pm in the green condition (but not 5:01pm) you'll have to extend the expression to look at the minutes as well

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "='ms-fontColor-white ' + if(indexOf(toLocaleTimeString(@now), 'AM') > -1 || Number(substring(toLocaleTimeString(@now),0,indexOf(toLocaleTimeString(@now),':'))) < 4, 'ms-bgColor-green', 'ms-bgColor-red')"
  }
}
```

In the above I'm using the standard Microsoft red and green classes for background color (with white text). If you'd rather apply this to `background-color` with a custom color value you can just take the expression starting with the `if` and swap out the class names with your color values.

Comment: thank you so much. i dont know how to tweak this code (i have no IT background) but this gives me a good start. i tried the exact syntax you provided, the background turned green for all the value and the time format changed to whole number.